# PDF file not shownig on mozila but work fine in chrome .

Tags: php, pdf

I am using this code to download pdf file  . its work fine in chrome but in mozila it create .htm file .Any can help me about this

```
   header("Pragma: public"); 
   header("Expires: 0");
   header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
   header("Cache-Control: private", false);
   header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
   header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
   readfile('phpToPDF/examples/pdf/'.$filename);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to terminate current script. that's why you are getting .htm extension on Mozilla. 
use exit(); at the end of your code.

```
header("Pragma: public"); 
   header("Expires: 0");
   header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
   header("Cache-Control: private", false);
   header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
   header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
   readfile('phpToPDF/examples/pdf/'.$filename);
   exit();
```